# Object in Edit Mode has blue overlay that intersects with other objects

Tags: objects, interface, edit-mode

I've been working on my MacBook within Blender and noticed that, whenever I go to edit an object, there's a blue tinge that coats the object. This is in edit view, solid. I can't seem to get rid of the overlay, and even worse, it intersects with other meshes in the scene even if they aren't touching. Anyone know what this could be?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in a previous version of Blender on Mac via steam. Downloading the newest version will solve the issue.